# How come system snapshots are so small in size?

Tags: linux, snapshot, btrfs

So let’s say a have a file called `bob` with the size of 10GB in `/home`. I make a snapshot of `/home` and delete the original `bob` file. However I can still access the bob file because I have a snapshot it. My question is how come the hard disk drive is not going to be full if I keep doing these a number of times? Becuase the size of the snapshot is very small.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about LVM snapshots then [this explains it pretty well](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshotintro.html):

> A wonderful facility provided by LVM is 'snapshots'. This allows the
>   administrator to create a new block device which presents an exact
>   copy of a logical volume, frozen at some point in time.

If you understand how file systems work, you understand that when you delete a file—such as `bob`—from your system, the file itself is not removed. But rather the inode entry for that file is removed. The data still exists on the volume. The snapshot takes a frozen image of the LVM table at that point in time and—this is key—it notes the inode entry used.

Meaning when you access data via a snapshot, it is really just remapping the LVM metadata to the in odes connected to that source data. And since post-snapshot you will not be given access to the inodes used by the system in the previous snapshots, that data is still retained on a deep file system level.

So an LVM snapshot is essentially a “delta” of your filesystem in one past state compared to what it is in it’s current state and done in a way that assures any “roll backs” to past data are retained.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep snapshots of a file or files, they do not get duplicated. There is only a single copy of the data that all snapshots refer to until you try to change a version, then you get new data. Hence "copy on write".